# How to run startup commands on loading Python Interactive window in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to execute some startup commands before starting or resetting the Python Interactive Window (IPython) within VSCode.
As I have been check in the documentation and in the parameters settings, I was able to identify the correct parameter:

> Python > Data Science: **Run Startup Commands**
>
> A series of Python instructions or iPython magic commands separated by '\n' that will be
> executed when the interactive window loads. For instance, set this to
> '%load_ext autoreload\n%autoreload 2' to automatically reload changes
> made to imported files without having to restart the interactive
> session.

However, when I insert my desirable python commands they not work as expected. As an example I tried to load the numpy package inserting 'import numpy as np', but when I start a new Python Interactive Window it outputs:

```
np is not defined
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: This option is now moved to `Jupyter>Run Startup Commands` as of VSCode 1.74.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes `''`, just `import numpy as np` and don't forget to separate instructions with `\n`.